# how to downgrade ubuntu kernel using bash script

Tags: apt, 18.04, kernel

How to downgrade ubuntu kernel using bash script

OS version

> PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.6

Kernel version

> 5.4.0-107-generic

For example I would like to downgrade to 5.4.0-105-generic. 
What is the right procedure, can that be done through bash script.

Comment: This may be a [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why do you want to downgrade kernel?

Comment: You can reboot and choose an older kernel in the "Advanced options" in the GRUB menu.

Comment: do you have both already installed?if so it is not a bash problem but a settings in /etc/grub/default

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I've some vendor dependency with the kernel version so I would like to install preferred kernel version. Over 100s of servers built with new kernels which is available but I would like to have downgrade my kernel to vendor specific version due to dependency.

Comment: I do not have the preferred kernel installed, but I would like to script out if my preferred kernel version is not installed and is not same as the currently installed kernel version then install downgrade to preferred. This is a specific requirement of specific type.

Comment: Is there way I can install lower kernel version in both the case whether preferred kernel already loaded and installed but system running with newer kernel version or preferred kernel is not installed or loaded. what is the right step to do this.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi "Advanced options" - Is there way to do it using script. say for example my preferred kernel is not installed or not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

preferred_k_version="5.4.0-105-generic"

#1) check if its already installed or not and check if its available repo

```
dpkg -l | grep "linux-image-${preferred_k_version}"

apt-cache search linux-image-${preferred_k_version} | awk '{print $1}' | sed -e s/^linux-image-//
```

#2) if not installed then install else proceed with step3

```
apt-get install -y linux-image-${preferred_k_version}
```

#3) get the preferred kernel version position and load:

```
preferred_k_position=$(awk -F' '$1=="menuentry " || $1=="submenu " {print i++ " : " $2}; /\\tmenuentry / {print "\\t" i-1"\>"j++ " : " $2};' /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep "${preferred_k_version}" | grep -v recovery | awk '{ print $1}' | sed 's/ //g') sed -i "s/GRUB_DEFAULT=0/GRUB_DEFAULT="${preferred_k_position}"/g" /etc/default/grub

echo $preferred_k_position

1>2
```

#4) update grub

```
sed -i "s/GRUB_DEFAULT=0/GRUB_DEFAULT=\"${preferred_k_position}\"/g" /etc/default/grub update-grub
```

#5) reboot

```
reboot now
```

#6) then login and check to confirm whether preferred kernel is installed or not.

```
uname -r 
5.4.0-105-generic
```

I've just written here the steps and this can be scripted out.

Comment: I've edited my question and answer and steps how to downgrade a kernel version from 5.4.0-107-generic to 5.4.0-105-generic.